# How to define an interface for a FormControl value?

Tags: angular, typescript, form-control

I want to get an ability to define an interface for a FormControl value. It will be very helpful in templates

I would't like to use any wrappers for that.

In a component

```
control = new FormControl({a:'some value'});
```

In a template

```
<div>{{control.value?.a}}</div>
```

Seems there is no ability to know a type of a value

I would like IDE can understand what kind of data the value contains

Comment: I'm not sure whether you can do that since I think that form inputs can only be strings or arrays

Comment: No, it can be whatever you want. The coupled question here how to define an interface for FormGroup...

Comment: @constantant something [like this](https://itnext.io/help-keep-angular-forms-type-safe-ca35f7b2edf8) not sure though

Comment: @SouravDutta thanks, but it is about a wrapper there :)

Comment: Try [@ng-stack/forms](https://github.com/KostyaTretyak/ng-stack/tree/master/projects/forms)